# Why this "segfault" with dplyr arrange function in R

Tags: r, dplyr

Following code consistently produces crash on my R system 3.2.2 :

```
> R.version
               _                           
platform       i486-slackware-linux-gnu    
arch           i486                        
os             linux-gnu                   
system         i486, linux-gnu             
status                                     
major          3                           
minor          2.2                         
year           2015                        
month          08                          
day            14                          
svn rev        69053                       
language       R                           
version.string R version 3.2.2 (2015-08-14)
nickname       Fire Safety               

> lll = list(list(5,3,4), list(5,3,7), list(6,2,1), list(6,1,3), list(5,2,1))
> dd = data.frame(do.call(rbind, lll))
> dd
  X1 X2 X3
1  5  3  4
2  5  3  7
3  6  2  1
4  6  1  3
5  5  2  1

> dplyr::arrange(dd, X1)

 *** caught segfault ***
address (nil), cause 'memory not mapped'

Traceback:
 1: .Call("dplyr_arrange_impl", PACKAGE = "dplyr", data, dots)
 2: arrange_impl(.data, dots)
 3: arrange_.tbl_df(tbl_df(.data), .dots = dots)
 4: arrange_(tbl_df(.data), .dots = dots)
 5: as.data.frame(arrange_(tbl_df(.data), .dots = dots))
 6: arrange_.data.frame(.data, .dots = lazyeval::lazy_dots(...))
 7: arrange_(.data, .dots = lazyeval::lazy_dots(...))
 8: dplyr::arrange(dd, X1)

Possible actions:
1: abort (with core dump, if enabled)
2: normal R exit
3: exit R without saving workspace
4: exit R saving workspace
```

Why is this crash occurring and how can I correct it?

Comment: How did you install dplyr?

Comment: The columns are still `list` if you check the `str(dd)`.  The `lll` is a nested list.  You may need `dd <- data.frame(do.call(rbind, lapply(lll, unlist)))`

Comment: What is the best way to convert 'lll' to a dataframe?

Comment: I get `Error: Unsupported vector type list` with dplyr 0.5.0 on R-devel (3.4.0).  What is `packageVersion("dplyr")` ?

Comment: packageVersion("dplyr") : [1] ‘0.4.3’

Comment: you might try updating to 0.5.0 (although your R version is also out of date ... ideally you would update both ...)

Answer (score 2):

It is a nested `list`, so one way would be to `unlist` the inner `list`, `rbind` the outer `list` and convert to `data.frame`

```
dd <- data.frame(do.call(rbind, lapply(lll, unlist)))
arrange(dd, X1)
#  X1 X2 X3
#1  5  3  4
#2  5  3  7
#3  5  2  1
#4  6  2  1
#5  6  1  3
```

---

Or use `purrr/dplyr`

```
library(purrr)
lll%>% 
   transpose %>%
   map(lift(c))  %>%
   setNames(., paste0("X", seq_along(.))) %>%
   data.frame() %>%
   arrange(X1)
```

Answer (score 2):

This has to be either a bug in `dplyr`, a bug in R core, or an incompatibility between the compiled component of `dplyr` and R core.  It's not supposed to be possible to do *anything* from within the R language that causes the interpreter to crash.

Not being particularly familiar with dplyr myself, I would guess that an incompatibility is the most probable explanation and a bug in dplyr is second-most probable.  An incompatibility could arise, for instance, if you installed dplyr with `install.packages` and then upgraded R core and didn't reinstall dplyr.  R core has defensive mechanisms that are supposed to prevent incompatible compiled-code modules from being picked up by a newer interpreter, but they don't always work.

If you can still reproduce the problem with the latest versions of R and dplyr, after having wiped out `$HOME/R` if it exists and then reinstalled dplyr, I would recommend filing a bug report at https://github.com/hadley/dplyr/issues.

Comment: I had installed dplyr with "install.packages". I have also updated R but not sure before or after dplyr. I am trying to update both now.

Answer (score 0):

I found following code also to work properly:

```
> dd = data.frame(t(sapply(lll, unlist)))
> dd
  X1 X2 X3
1  5  3  4
2  5  3  7
3  6  2  1
4  6  1  3
5  5  2  1
> str(dd)
'data.frame':   5 obs. of  3 variables:
 $ X1: num  5 5 6 6 5
 $ X2: num  3 3 2 1 2
 $ X3: num  4 7 1 3 1
> 
> arrange(dd, X1)
  X1 X2 X3
1  5  3  4
2  5  3  7
3  5  2  1
4  6  2  1
5  6  1  3
>
```

The do.call and rbind functions are not needed here.